# Using R here function to export csv

Tags: r

I am using the here function with an R project:

```
library(here)
```

The here function specifies by project folder:

```
getwd()

[1] "\\\\campus/user/test"
```

I am trying to export a dataframe as a csv file in a folder I have already created called "Output data":

```
df1 <- data.frame(x0=1:5,
                    x1=rnorm(5),
                    x2=c("M","F","M","F","F"))
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work:

```
write.csv(here::here("Output data", "df1.csv", row.names=FALSE))
```

Instead I get the error message:

```
"","x"
"1","\\\\campus/user/test/Output data/df1.csv/FALSE"
Warning message:
Arguments must be unnamed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data frame to be written must be the first argument to `write.csv()`. Here is an example that writes the data frame from the OP to a `./data` subdirectory of a project.

First, we'll create an empty file called `hereTest.csv` in a `./data` subdirectory of the current R project, and demonstrate that `here::here()` finds it.

```
# Step 1: outside R, create a file called hereTest.csv in ./data directory

library(here)
getwd()
here("hereTest.csv")
```

Output from the `here()` function:

```
> here("hereTest.csv")
[1] "/Volumes/USBDISK/gitrepos/datascience/hereTest.csv"
```

Next, we'll create the data frame from the original post and write it to disk using `write.csv()` and `here.here()`.

```
# create df per OP
df1 <- data.frame(x0=1:5,
                  x1=rnorm(5),
                  x2=c("M","F","M","F","F"))

# write df to the file by concatenating the directory
# with the file name

write.csv(df1,file=here::here("data","hereTest.csv"), row.names=FALSE)
```

...and the output, viewed in Atom:

[image]

### A Base R Approach: Relative Pathing

Having answered the question in the original post, given that the directory where the file will be stored is passed as argument to `here()`, one can achieve the same outcome by simply using relative pathing. In Linux a relative path is a path that is based on the user's current location, in contrast to an absolute path that does not take the user's current location into account.

To use relative pathing within R we can use a single dot `.` to represent the current directory, or two dots `..` to represent the parent directory.

If an R project has been loaded, the root directory of the project is the current working directory, so we can use `.` to work with paths that are subdirectories of the project's R working directory.

For example, if I select Open Project from the project pulldown menu to load my `datascience` R project in RStudio and then run `getwd()`, it returns the root directory for my project.

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Volumes/USBDISK/gitrepos/datascience"
```

At this point in my R code I can use `.` to refer to the project root directory with R functions that reference external file names.

To illustrate writing a file with `write.csv()` using this technique we will use the same data frame from the original question.

To write a file to a subdirectory called `testdata`, first we check whether the directory exist and create it if it doesn't already exist.

```
# create the subdirectory if it doesn't already exist
if(!dir.exists("./testdata")) dir.create("./testdata")
```

Now we can write the file by referencing it with the relative path name.

```
# write the df as a CSV
write.csv(df1,"./testdata/df1.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

Finally, we'll use a combination of `more` and `system()` to have the operating system print the file into the R log, illustrating that the file has been written correctly:

```
> system("more ./testdata/df1.csv")
"x0","x1","x2"
1,-1.68645061094609,"M"
2,-0.281506055616705,"F"
3,1.68718211014908,"M"
4,1.38728455758571,"F"
5,-1.25623771815585,"F"
```

Comment: That's great @Len Greski - many thanks for explaining things so clearly.

Comment: @KT_1 - FYI, I added an alternative solution that doesn't require `here::here()`. It's based on relative pathing.